# Check two conditions with two different outcomes (ternary operators)

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I created a variable,

```
newval1 = lb + (ub - lb)*rnd.nextDouble();
```

which has to lie between two values, `bounds[0]` and `bounds[1]`. Currently I implemented this check in two lines with ternary operators:

```
            newval1 = ((newval1<bounds[0]) ? bounds[0] : newval1);
            newval1 = ((newval1>bounds[1]) ? bounds[1] : newval1);
```

I've no doubt there is a more efficient way of comparing `newval1` to these bounds, preferable in 1 line. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can do it in one line with ternary operators (`newval1 < bounds[0] ? bounds[0] : newval1 > bounds[1] ? bounds[1] : newval1`), but why not just write out a few `if`s? There's nothing wrong with a little bit of verbosity if it leads to clearer code.

Comment: @resueman: in your example, is it a nested ternary operator?

Comment: Yes. It's basically the same as what you have, just on one line. (I'm not saying you should use that though. It's just an example of a one-line solution).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
val = Math.min(bounds[1], Math.max(bounds[0], val));
```

Comment: btw, this does exactly the same as you code, but written in a more common way.